# hover na ancora e icon

Tags: html, css, css3, css-hover

cada item da minha lista possui um icon na frente, mas, o hover não funciona para os dois ao mesmo tempo. quando passo o mouse no icon o 'texto' acompanha o efeito do hover, mas quando passo no 'texto' o icon não acompanha o efeito. o que pode estar causando isso e como posso resolver?

```css
.nav-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.nav-container ul {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-container li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-container li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
  transition: .2s;
}

.nav-container li a:hover {
  color: #0068AF
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<nav class="nav-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> texto </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> texto </a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Veja o exemplo na própria pergunta. O problema relatado não ocorre.

Answer (score -2):

Pode ser alguma coisa no resto dos seus estilos que está passando por cima desse, porque só nesse pedaço de código está funcionando da maneira que você quer